# How to extract text between certain patterns using regular expression (RegEx)?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-extraction, regex-greedy

My text:

```
27/07/18, 12:02 PM - user_a: https://www.youtube.com/
 Watch this
27/07/18, 12:15 PM - user_b: <Media omitted>
27/07/18, 12:52 PM - user_b: Read this fully
some text
some text
.
some text
27/07/18, 12:56 PM - user_c: text ..
```

Here I want to extract the messages sent by the users. I tried two regex. But I didn't get the answer I wanted

First regex:

```
re.findall(r''+user_name+ ':(.*)', data)
```

Here I couldn't able to extract the text multi lines

Second regex:

```
re.findall(r''+ user_name + ':[^(:)]*', data)
```

Here I couldn't able to extract the full text having a hyper link .i.e., I could able to get only "https". It considers the symbol ":" as an endpoint.

How do I handle this ? Any kind of suggestions would be really great & helpful

Comment: Try something like [`user_\w*: \s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+\/).+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/TkugEe/1) (replace `\w*` with `name`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
user_b: (.*?)(?=^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/rAvNHc/1).

Note the usage of `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL`. The first flag is needed to match beginning of line patterns over multiline text, whereas `re.DOTALL` is needed to enable the `.` to match newlines too.

---

In Python:

```
import re
data = '''
27/07/18, 12:02 PM - user_a: https://www.youtube.com/
 Watch this
27/07/18, 12:15 PM - user_b: <Media omitted>
27/07/18, 12:52 PM - user_b: Read this fully
some text
some text
.
some text
27/07/18, 12:56 PM - user_c: text ..
'''
usern = 'user_b'

pattern = re.compile(r""+usern+r": (.*?)(?=^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})",re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
print(re.findall(pattern,data))
```

Prints:

```
['<Media omitted>\n', 'Read this fully\nsome text\nsome text\n.\nsome text\n']
```

Comment: Won't you have the same issue as your comment to me where if the client starts a line with the same date/time format?  :-)  I think to make it more reliable the logging needs to include a string of characters unlikely to ever be entered that can be matched on (but if it's a field with no entry validations it's a matter of time before some user enters the magic string).

Comment: Yes, that's correct Gary. I'll modify the lookahead to make it even more restrictive when I get home, as `(?=^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}, [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M - user)`

Comment: I was updating mine with that same pattern when i realized the problem.

Comment: What problem is there if using `(?=^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}, [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M - user)`?

Comment: I didn't include the text "user" as I suspect that was just for example and real user_id's won't match that pattern.  Who knows though. Posters rarely supply all the info one needs to properly answer a question so we work with what we are given :-/

Comment: Yeah, I feel you on that one .. :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe your regex should be: `user_b: (.*?)^[0-9]`. After your user is found, match the rest of the line until a number as the first character of a line is found (the next entry).  Make sure to turn on multi-line.

[See a demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/rsxTIx/1)

Comment: Will fail if a number is at the beginning of the string to be matched.

Comment: Good catch!  I was then inclined to match the date/time instead of just the number but since it's user input, that could be matched as well as who knows what they will enter!  I would still do that if the logging could add a sequence of characters or something to look for instead that had a low chance of being entered by users.

Comment: Yeah, a lookahead is needed for the exact dd/mm/yy pattern.